# список в несколько рядов и несколько строк

Tags: html, css, css3, ul

Приветствую

У меня есть список `<ul></ul>`, содержащий значительное число `<li></li>` элементов.

Хочу добиться того, чтоб они были выведены в несколько строк и несколько столбцов, при этом все сделать в рамках одного `<ul>` и одного `<div>`, без привлечения таблиц и других сущностей.

Если бы я хотел выводить в столбец, то для

определил бы

```
li {
    display: block;
}
```

Если бы хотел выводить в строку, то для

определил бы

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

а вот как сделать и сроку и столбец, например, чтобы строк было не больше 3 (столбцов сколько угодно) или столбцов было не больше 5 (строк сколько угодно)

вроде сталкивался с решением для css3, но благополучно забыл :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `flex` , например, так:

```css
ul.s3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul.s3 li {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

ul.s5 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul.s5 li {
  flex-basis: 17%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
li {margin: 2px;}
```

```html
<ul class="s3">
  <li>меню1</li>  <li>меню2</li>  <li>меню3</li>
  <li>меню4</li>  <li>меню5</li>  <li>меню6</li>
  <li>меню7</li>  <li>меню8</li>  <li>меню8</li>
  <li>меню10</li>  <li>меню11</li>  <li>меню12</li>
  <li>меню13</li>  <li>меню14</li>  <li>меню15</li>
  <li>меню16</li>  <li>меню17</li>  <li>меню18</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul class="s5">
  <li>меню1</li>  <li>меню2</li>  <li>меню3</li>
  <li>меню4</li>  <li>меню5</li>  <li>меню6</li>
  <li>меню7</li>  <li>меню8</li>  <li>меню8</li>
  <li>меню10</li>  <li>меню11</li>  <li>меню12</li>
  <li>меню13</li>  <li>меню14</li>  <li>меню15</li>
  <li>меню16</li>  <li>меню17</li>  <li>меню18</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Этот вариант подошел, спасибо. Минусов пока не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

для столбцов решение нашел:

```
column-count: 5;
-webkit-column-count: 5;
-moz-column-count: 5;
```

А вот кол-во рядов можно вычислит на основании свойств

```
column-gap
column-width
```

Но в явном виде задать вроде как не получится :(

Возникла новая проблема (см. рисунок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

css код:

```
.submenu {
    position:                   absolute;
    top:                        calc(50px + 21px);
    left:                       0px;

    margin:                     0px;
    padding:                    0px;

    width:                      100vw;

    background: #fff0f0;
}

.submenu ul {
    list-style:                 none;

    margin:                     0px;
    padding:                    0px;    

    column-count:               3;
    -moz-column-count:          3;
    -webkit-column-count:       3;

    column-gap:                 20px;
}

.submenu > ul li {
    cursor:                     pointer;    

    display:                    block;

    position:                   relative;

    width:                      300px;
    height:                     100%;


    margin:                     0px;
    padding:                    0px 10px;

    font-family:                OpenSansLight;
    font-size:                  14px;
    font-weight:                400;

    text-transform:             uppercase;
    text-align:                 left;
    line-height:                25px;

    color:                      #000000;

    margin: 2px 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

1. пропала нижняя граница у TEXT #7
2. нижняя граница перенеслась в ряд где TEXT #8
3. почему-то по центру больше элементов, хотя хотелось бы слева больше, справа меньше
4. если посмотреть 3 ряда, то 2ой ряд выше на 1px, чем 1ый и 3ий

Comment: Не форматируйте так код никогда.

Comment: Саша, а по существу - в чем проблема?

Comment: Чтобы поддерживать такое форматирование, необходимо либо выстраивать все по самому длинному селектору, либо по самому длинному свойству. Если вы работаете в одиночку, то в принципе никакой проблемы нет, можно писать хоть лесенкой. Но в целом, людям это точно неудобно, и автоматически такое не поддерживает ни один редактор, насколько мне известно, а это значит лишняя трата времени.

Comment: А где можно посмотреть как правильно писать (как говорится - век живи, век учись)

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос. Возможно вам стоит присмотреться к CSS Grid. С ее помощью можно легко управлять, как количеством столбцов, так и строк.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
</ul>
```